# An existing connection was forcefully closed by remote host

Tags: ios, networking, soap, nsurlconnection, nsurl

I am working with nsurlconnections. When ever map is moved im updating the details to server using nsurlconnection. Whenever I am making a new request, I am actually canceling the existing connection by performing

```
[Conneciton cancel];
Conneciton=nill;
```

By performing this, I am receiving the error

> An existing connection was forcefully closed by remote host

in the service end. It does not effect app logics or users. I am still having my log with a lot of data with this error.

How can I solve this?

Comment: If you are cancelling the connection then you can ignore any error messages emitted by it.  Just keep some *cancelled state*.  Also your name is interesting... is it because you worry about code?

Answer (score 1):

Either don't cancel it or add code on the server side to enqueue the error and emit it to the logs only if it doesn't get a replacement request in a timely manner.

For that matter, clients go away, networks fail, and any number of other things cause connections to drop, so your server probably shouldn't bother logging anything when that happens anyway.  It should just gracefully cancel the request or whatever.  :-)